# What is this rubber thing I found by the sink?

Tags: kitchens, sink

I found this rubber thing by the kitchen sink of my new place and I'm trying to figure out what it is. Any ideas? it looks like some kind of stopper but it doesn't seem to fit anything I see. 
[image]

Comment: Wine bottle stopper??

Comment: ha, could be. Not sure why the people who lived here left it. I guess i'll keep it just in case it's something important.

Comment: you were right! i googled a bit and I found it: http://www.vacuvin.com/270/Vacuum_Wine_Saver.html

Comment: Wow.  I can see it now that you mention it but I'd have never come up with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's a wine bottle stopper. Thanks to UNECS.
http://www.vacuvin.com/270/Vacuum_Wine_Saver.html

Comment: What a guess aye lol